# JavaFX Window always on top of Java Swing JFrame - Wrong Behaviour

Tags: java, swing, listview, javafx, jframe

I have a Java Swing application. For one of `javax.swing.JFrame`, I use JFXPanel to embed JavaFX content. In JFXPanel, there is ListView (JFrame => JFXPanel => ListView). Double click on ListView's item, will open new JavaFX browser Window, to load HTML content of it's URL.

Assuming 3 windows:

```
Window-A: Main application window (Swing).
Window-B: JFrame with JFXPanel (contain's ListView).
Window-C: JavaFX browser window
```

Once Window-C is open, it always stay on top of any other Windows (Window-A, Window-B, & even Netbean IDE Window). When click on Window-A / Window-B, the Window is actived but always stay behind Window-C. The only way to have complete view on Window-A / Window-B, is to move Window-C away so not to overlap with them.

I tried setting these for Window-C, but with no effect:

```
stage.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
stage.initModality(Modality.NONE);
```

The intended behaviour is, whenever Window-A / Window-B / Window-C is clicked, it should stay on top, all the other windows should go behind it.

Any idea how to make this work? Is it a mistake to invoke pure JavaFX Window (Window-C) from Swing application?

Below is my code snippet:

```
public class StockNews extends JFrame {
    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    Scene scene;
    VBox vbox;

    java.util.List<FeedItem> messages;
    ListView<FeedItem> newsListView;
    ObservableList<FeedItem> messages_o;

    public StockNews(java.util.List<FeedItem> messages) {
        super();
        this.messages = messages;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vbox = new VBox();
                scene = new Scene(vbox, 500, 500);
                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

                messages_o = FXCollections.observableArrayList (messages);
                newsListView = new ListView<>(messages_o); 

                newsListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<FeedItem>, 
                    ListCell<FeedItem>>() {
                        @Override 
                        public ListCell<FeedItem> call(ListView<FeedItem> list) {
                            // draw single cell
                            return new DisplaySingleNews();
                        }
                    }
                );

                // Double-clicked ListView's item, will open new JavaFX browser Window, loading HTML content of it's URL
                newsListView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        if (event.getClickCount() > 1) {
                            FeedItem msg = newsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                            URL link = msg.getLink();

                            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);

                            // This window always stay on top, even not active. below 2 lines have no effect
                            stage.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
                            stage.initModality(Modality.NONE);

                            WebView browser = new WebView();
                            stage.setScene(new Scene(browser));
                            stage.show();

                            WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
                            webEngine.load(link.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

                vbox.getChildren().addAll(newsListView);
            }
        });

        this.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Right Window: Main Swing Application Window (Window-A). Left Window: Swing's JFrame with JFXPanel (Window-B). Middle Window: JavaFX Window (Window-C)]

Comment: I would strongly recommend not mixing window types. If you have to mix JavaFX and Swing, either use only `JFrame`s and no `Stage`s (embedding all JavaFX content in `JFXPanel`s), or use only `Stage`s and no `JFrame`s (embedding all Swing content in `SwingNode`s).

Comment: I changed my JavaFX window (Window-C) to use JFrame with JFXPanel, it works for me now. @James_D Thanks for your suggestion.